# MongoDB connection with Django i am getting below error after configuration

Tags: django, mongodb, connection

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django' isn't an available database backend or couldn't be imported. Check the above exception. To use one of the built-in backends, use 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to use MongoDB with Django is by using `DJONGO` package. It is a kind of django package developed only for the purpose to make Django compatible with MongoDB.

1. How to install `djongo`

```
pip install djongo
```

Also, Addi it `requirement.txt` to capture requirements for next time.

2. Update database settings as

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'your-db-name',
        'CLIENT': {
           'host': 'your-db-host',
        }
    }
}
```

3. Run migrations

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

and then run migrate changes to DB

```
python manage.py migrate
```

`djongo` is compatible with `Python >=3.6` and `MongoDB>=3.4`.

Comment: After install python -m pip install pymongo[srv] it works i can runserver.

Comment: After applying default migrations i was getting errors in console so i followed below setp.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185942/why-i-am-getting-not-implemented-error-database-objects-do-not-implement-truth

Now i am not getting any kind of error and i am able to run django project with MongoDB successfully.

Answer (score 0):

After followed above steps i install python -m pip install pymongo[srv] it works i can run django project.

After applying default migrations i was getting errors in console so i followed below step.

[Why I am getting "Not Implemented Error: Database objects do not implement truth value testing or bool()." while running makemigration cmd in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70185942/why-i-am-getting-not-implemented-error-database-objects-do-not-implement-truth)

Now i am not getting any kind of error and i am able to run django project with MongoDB successfully.